# Google Sheets - Split Formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet where we paste values copied from a pdf into a column, such as:

> 2715411.0 28.10.2021 600.00

In Google sheets there are columns with formulas that split these values, one of each is:

> =ArrayFormula(INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(C2:C274, "\s", "♥"),"♥"),ROW(C2)-ROW(C2),1))

This formula is returning "**2715411**" instead of "**2715411.0**". I've tested the formula if the value was "**2715411.1**" and it works so I'm assuming it's because the number is being "rounded".

Another thing to take into consideration is that sometimes the number we paste is something like "**32434346** 28.10.2021 600.00" so having always decimal places can't be the answer.

Can anyone help?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the FORMULA is RETURNING the value without the decimal point, or gsheets is just DISPLAYING the CELL VALUE without the decimal point?  Format the cell as a string and alter the formula to concatenate a `>` to the start and a `<` to the end, and you'll see the actual returned value.

Comment: @MatBailie Cells are plain text and I've changed the formula to "=ArrayFormula(INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(C275:C, "\s", "<"),"♥"),ROW(C2)-ROW(C2),1))" and it does show the ".0". Now how can I make it show?

Comment: I guess using the formula "=ArrayFormula(LEFT(C275:C, SEARCH(" ",C275:C)-1))" instead, does the trick

Comment: You still haven't demonstrated that it's the formula.  Type `2715411.0` in to a blank cell and it will display `2715411`, so even when the formula returns the value you want, it can display differently.  It's entirely about how the cell displays the contained value.  Play with formatting options.

Comment: It may not be the formula but the cell format was "plain text" when using both formulas (as is) and only when I used the new one I was able to see ".0". I don't think I completely tried what you suggested, I just changed "♥" to "<" and was able to see ".0" right away but without changing anything else, the split wasn't made correctly. So your suggestion did point me into believing that it may not be the formula but, as is, and with plain text, it didn't work for me. You helped me anyway and thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

```
=ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(C2:C274,".","♦")," "),"♦","."))
```